GEKKO optimizer converging on wrong point
I am using the GEKKO optimization package (https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in python. Since my problem sometimes includes integer variables I run with the following options to get optimization for a steady state mixed integer problem (APOPT):
m.options.IMODE = 3
m.options.SOLVER = 1

The optimizer finds a solution that is not optimal. Consider the following minimal working example:
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
# Define objective
def obj(x1, x2):
    return x1*0.04824647331436083 + x2*0.1359023029124411 + x1*x2*(0.5659570743890336)

# Define variables
x1 = m.Var(lb=-0.7280376309420935, ub=0.2719623690579065)
x2 = m.Var(lb=-0.8912733608888134, ub=0.10872663911118663)

u = m.Intermediate(obj(x1,x2))
m.Maximize(u)

# Solve the problem
m.options.SOLVER = 'APOPT'
m.solve(disp=False)

# Print the results
print(f'x1: {x1.value[0]}')
print(f'x2: {x2.value[0]}')
print(f'u: {u.value[0]}')

This gives the output:
x1: 0.27196236906
x2: 0.10872663911
u: 0.044632524297

However, consider the following solution and its utility:
x1 = -0.7280376309420935
x2 = -0.8912733608888134
obj(x1, x2)

This results in a utility of 0.2109871851434535

A contour plot verifies that there are two local maxima. Gekko solvers report local minima or maxima when the Karush Kuhn Tucker (KKT) conditions are satisfied.

from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
# Define objective
def obj(x1, x2):
    return x1*0.04824647331436083 + x2*0.1359023029124411 + x1*x2*(0.5659570743890336)

# Define variables
x1 = m.Var(lb=-0.7280376309420935, ub=0.2719623690579065)
x2 = m.Var(lb=-0.8912733608888134, ub=0.10872663911118663)

u = m.Intermediate(obj(x1,x2))
m.Maximize(u)

# Solve the problem
m.options.SOLVER = 'APOPT'
m.solve(disp=False)

# Print the results
print(f'x1: {x1.value[0]}')
print(f'x2: {x2.value[0]}')
print(f'u: {u.value[0]}')

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate grid of values
x1v = np.linspace(-0.7280376309420935, 0.2719623690579065, 400)
x2v = np.linspace(-0.8912733608888134, 0.10872663911118663, 400)
x1g, x2g = np.meshgrid(x1v, x2v)
ug = obj(x1g, x2g)

# Create contour plot
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3.5))
contour = plt.contourf(x1g, x2g, ug, levels=50, cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar(contour); plt.xlabel('x1'); plt.ylabel('x2')
plt.tight_layout(); plt.show()

For problems with multiple local minima or maxima, there are multi-start methods to assist in finding the global optimum: Multi-start implementation with GEKKO  Below is an implementation of hyperopt that is used to find the global optimum. hyperopt is a Python package for performing hyperparameter optimization with a variety of optimization algorithms including random search, Tree-structured Parzen Estimator (TPE), and adaptive TPE, as well as a simple and flexible way to define the search space for the hyperparameters.
from gekko import GEKKO
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp
from hyperopt import STATUS_OK, STATUS_FAIL

# Define the search space for the multi-start parameters
space = {'x1': hp.quniform('x1', -0.72, 0.27, 0.1),
         'x2': hp.quniform('x2', -0.89, 0.10, 0.1)}

def objective(params):
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    x1 = m.Var(lb=-0.7280376309420935, ub=0.2719623690579065)
    x2 = m.Var(lb=-0.8912733608888134, ub=0.10872663911118663)
    x1.value = params['x1']
    x2.value = params['x2']
    u = m.Intermediate(x1*0.04824647331436083 + x2*0.1359023029124411 + x1*x2*(0.5659570743890336))
    m.Maximize(u)
    m.options.SOLVER = 1
    m.solve(disp=False,debug=False)
    obj = m.options.objfcnval
    if m.options.APPSTATUS==1:
        s=STATUS_OK
    else:
        s=STATUS_FAIL
    m.cleanup()
    return {'loss':obj, 'status': s, 'x1':x1.value[0],'x2':x2.value[0],'u':u.value[0]}

best = fmin(objective, space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=50)
sol = objective(best)
print(f"Solution Status: {sol['status']}")
print(f"Objective: {-sol['loss']:.2f}")
print(f"x1: {sol['x1']}")
print(f"x2: {sol['x2']}")
print(f"u: {sol['u']}")

This produces the global maximum with the TPE algorithm to find the best optimal solution by changing the initial guess values using a Bayesian approach.
Solution Status: ok
Objective: 0.21
x1: -0.72803763094
x2: -0.89127336089
u: 0.21098718514


Thank you so much for looking into this. I apologize for failing to create a minimal working example. I have edited my question accordingly.

Your new answers solves my problem! I was not aware that I got stuck in a local maximum. Will try to implement using hyperopt like you suggested. Thank you so much for the support! GEKKO is amazing.

Quick follow-up question. I have approximately a hundred variables in the real case. Is that a problem for hyperopt and its search space definition?

And what should the search space parameters look like for 0/1 integer variables?

The search space are the initial guesses. hyperopt doesn't do an exhaustive search depending on the options that you select - you may need to tune the multi-start options to solve in a reasonable time. If there are integer variables, you probably only need hyperopt to find the root node (continuous solution) and then let branch and bound take it from there. Please ask a new question if you need help implementing a 2-phase initialization (NLP) followed by the integer solution (MINLP).

Thank you, I have now solved this problem so I will leave it as is. :) Thank you again.
